# Elasticsearch - find exists index patterns

Tags: python-2.7, rally, elasticsearch-5, pyral

I'm using Python script that fetch data from Rally API, manipulate it and send to Elasticsearch. 
I'm trying to figure how to find my exist index/s in script code. My ES instance is quite simple:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'myIP', 'port': 9200}])
```

I cannot find where's exist index in this instance

**My purpose is to state a condition for updating my index/s data**

Any idea?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the solution and it's quite simple to use. Just type:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'host_ip', 'port': 9200}])

if es.indices.exists(index = 'index_name') 
 #set a condition here
```